# How can we store PDF files in Mongo Data Base using NODEJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

How to store PDF formatted data to mongo Database and how can we convert into base64 format.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the discussion on this link for the info

https://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/148smwbct0/storing-and-retrieving-pdf-files-using-mongodb

Summary::

1. Store the files directly in the document
   For example in Java you will just store byte[] in an attribute, look at his
   test:
   https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/com/mongodb/ByteTest.java#L188
2. Use GridFS
   You can find information about this here :
   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/
3. Create Reference to an external storage

   This one is not directly a "MongoDB" use case, but I think it is important
   to mention it. You can obviously store the files in some special storage
   and use MongoDB just for the meta data, and reference this file. I will
   take a stupid example but suppose you want to create a Video application,
   you can store the videos in YouTube and reference this into the document
   with all your application meta data.
   http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/translational-medicine-platform-sanofi-0

Comment: thanks for the help.My Question is when i am trying to save the pdf file into mongo db we should convert it into the base64 format.So i could'nt able to save the file into the mongo db.